# Explain this behaviour with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
board_1 = [[0]*4]*4
board_2 = [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
```

both the above methods yield the following list.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

but when we replace an element(3,3) in those list we get different result

```
board_1[3][3] = 1
```

this will yield

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

whereas, the below will get the correct output

```
board_2[3][3] = 1

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

why we get two different result?